# Add the Auth2.0 within Jmeter from Postman to generate Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, jmeter, authorization, postman, load-testing

Hi I have a collection in Postman which will not work unless i have a token and in order to
generate this token i have to add the following details per the image.
[image]
[image]

I want to add these same parameters within Jmeter so that my APIs will work... This is Auth 2.0 how can i add all those values within Jmeter...?

Answer (score 0):

There is no single place where you can put these parameters in JMeter because [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/) is a series of requests/responses so you need to implement all these requests which Postman makes under the hood with JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers and perform the [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of the dynamic parameters.

The requests can be even recorded using [JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) if you [configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling)